# DVI Thinkpad monitors through Intel on Dock

Tags: laptop, multiple-monitors, thinkpad, nvidia-graphics-card, optimus

Hardware is an Thinkpad T520 with Optimus technology.

Video Cards:

- Nvidia NVS 4200M
- Intel 3000 HD

Dock:

- Mini dock 433810U

With this dock + laptop combination, the external displays are not powered until Windows is booted with properly configured Optimus drivers. Selecting "integrated" or "discrete" graphics mode in bios cause the displays to not function at all.

1. Is it possible to always power the external DVI/DP displays (even at boot or in Linux)?
2. Use only the Intel video card?

As a proposed solution, could I simply remove the Nvidia card?

Answer (score 0):

Ah, the joy of having to many graphics card. Jokes aside, i am going to answer your questions in reverse order:

-2. No. On a lot of thinkpads, all outputs except the internal Display and the VGA out are connected to the Nvidia discrete graphics card, which means that anything drawn on external DVI/DP monitors has to pass through the Nvidia.

-1. Kind of. I would suggest you take a look at [PRIME](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PRIME) (which requires usage of the nouveau driver to function properly) and then to look at whatever script starts your disply manager, in which you have to paste a lot of display-detection and `xrandr --setprovider...` stuff. This would then configure your x server for your graphics card/ display situation, even before your login-window thing appears.

The exact stuff you have to modify depends on your display manager, your graphics cards, your display connections, etc. , but provided you tell me what exactly you are using and the outputs of `xrandr` before and after enabling the discrete card, i can probably help you out.